# Multipage plot with marrangeGrob not showing up in R markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am currently working on including a large number of plots in an R-markdown script. Because of the large number of plots I am using the marangeGrob function from the gridExtra package, which splits my plot_object (containing ~100 plots) over several pages with 9 plots (3x3) on each page. It works well when I run it in Rstudio. However for some reason the plots do not show up in the knitted document produced by the markdown file. Does anyone have an idea of what goes wrong? I provide a minimal example of the code below:

````
```{r example ,  results = 'asis', message = T, warning = T, fig.width = 14, fig.height = 12}

margin <-  ggplot2::theme(plot.margin = ggplot2::unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm"))
gridExtra::marrangeGrob(lapply(plot_object, "+", margin), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

}```
````

Comment: It does look "minimal" but it doesn't look "complete". There's not way to see what sort of data objects you are working with. Does your Rmd script load any packages?